# How to read HTML file body tag

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Please see [this page](http://www.taxmann.com/taxmannflashes/whatsnew.aspx?sid=9578&stype=1).

I am able to read HTML, but I want to pick out the `<Body>` tag and display it in a panel.

I have written this code:

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.taxmann.com/taxmannflashes/whatsnew.aspx?sid=9578&stype=1");

WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
string htmlResp = sr.ReadToEnd();
String htmlBody = "";

if (htmlResp.ToLower().Contains("<div id=\"dvreadmore\">"))
{
    int startIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("<div id=\"dvreadmore\">");
    int lastIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("</html>\n</div>");
    if (lastIndex == -1)
    {
        lastIndex = htmlResp.ToLower().IndexOf("</html></div>");
    }
    htmlBody = htmlResp.Substring(startIndex + 21, lastIndex + 7);
    String final = htmlBody;
}
```

I'm getting the value "null finalhtml body NUll value." I want to pick the `<Body>` tag.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com for dealing with reading html. It can also be installed via nuget.